# Is it an acceptable idea that I write HTML codes into JS codes?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Every website has some static codes which always are constant. For example header, footer, advertising box and ...!

Well I want to write all those static HTML codes into JS file, and as you know it will be catch. So loading will be faster. I mean Why user should download my fixed HTML codes all the time? I think I can catch them by that trick I mentioned.

However I don't have a lot of experience in this field. So will not I faced with some problems later if I do that?

Comment: yeah, not good unless you are using JSX or you know what you are doing

Comment: You might want to take a look at template engines.

Comment: You cannot gain performance, You'll have rendering issues, problems when You change Your code and etc. But it depends on what You moving to JS part. Better learn to use frontend frameworks like react, angular, ember and etc that work different, You'll like it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure wrapping your HTML in JS, and your "caching" idea (which is what I assume you meant by "catching") will both only *increase* the load time of the website. Caching is a thing already, and [one that can be controlled](http://dev.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/).

Comment: Sounds like you are over complicating things if you don't have experience with it. As mentioned use a front end framework instead of rolling your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing up view (HTML) and business logic (JS) is an anti-pattern as it violates [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
That said, it depends most on which kind of code you are mixing within the view: is it strictly related to that view's rendering?

If though your motivation is *loading will be faster* I think you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Disagree about separation of concerns. Lots of templates are stored in js for newer front end frameworks and it is trivial to use build tools to generate these from html files

Comment: right: and as I pointed out in my answer, they do so for the logic strictly related to the view. Though I don't think that because _lot of newer frontend frameworks_ are violating a pattern, that pattern is no more valid :)

Comment: @charlietfl I came back to this answer today: I think you have a point. Separation of template from JS doesn't always match with _separation of concerns_.